# ¿Qué son los KeyErrors?

Tags: python

He notado que cuando existen errores en el código el editor subraya la línea de código que rompe el programa además de sugerir que es lo que está mal, cómo: `NameError: name 'moneda' is not defined`  pero en otras ocasiones solo muestra `Keyerror` y un número, por ejemplo `Keyerror:20` ¿Qué son los KeyErrors? y por consiguiente ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlos?

Comment: Se entendería mejor si aportas un ejemplo mínimo que ilustre el error, como para tener una base desde la cual conversar.

Comment: creo que primero deberías saber que significa los errores, el `Keyerror:20` significa que no existe la clave `20` en un diccionario o lista

Comment: Ese error te aparecerá en una línea de este aspecto: `algo[v]`, y en ese caso `algo` es un diccionario, y `v` tiene el valor 20. El error simplemente te dice que no existe esa entrada (esa clave) en ese diccionario. No es un "error de google colab", es un típico error Python, que ocurre al intentar acceder a un dato inexistente en un diccionario.

Comment: ¡Exacto! Justo eso @Christian deseo saber en donde puedo consultar los significados de esos errores, y por lo que me comentas del `Keyerror:20` ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: @AbelSalasLeal Lo puedes ver en la [Documentacion de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: Creo que ya entendí @abulafia `Keyerror:v` es un error relacionado con listas y en esencia lo que me dice el valor `v` de mi lista no existe

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a todos! @abulafia puedes escribir la respuesta a la pregunta y así marcar la pregunta como resuelta si así quisieras.

Comment: En este sitio, no hay nada resuelto hasta que no hay una respuesta.. y cuando se resuelve, la pregunta se pone sola en verde ;).. no es necesario agregar nada al titulo...

Comment: Aprovecha a hacer el [tour] y tambien mira [ask] asi sabes como funciona todo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La duda es muy básica. Una búsqueda en google de "python keyerror" arroja muchos resultados. Sin embargo he observado que pocos de ellos están en castellano, así que voy a escribir una respuesta que pueda servir de referencia a otros con el mismo problema.

### Qué significa ese error

La excepción `KeyError` se produce cuando intentas acceder a una clave de un diccionario usando la sintaxis `diccionario[clave]` y la `clave` en cuestión no está en el diccionario.

Por ejemplo, considera el diccionario:

```
diccionario = { "nombre": "Juan", "edad": 27, "peso": 75 }
```

Puedes acceder a `diccionario["nombre"]` o `diccionario["edad"]`, etc. sin problemas para recuperar los datos ("Juan", 27). Sin embargo si intentas `diccionario["estatura"]`, por ejemplo, ya que esa clave no forma parte del diccionario, obtendrás el `KeyError`-

En tu caso la clave a la que intentas acceder y que te está causando el error, es 20. Las claves de un diccionario pueden ser números y no solo cadenas como en mi ejemplo (en realidad, pueden ser cualquier dato de tipo *inmutable*, lo que incluye también por ejemplo las tuplas).

### Cómo tratar el error

En la mayoría de los casos es un bug. Es decir, te has equivocado al escribir el nombre de la clave, o al suponer que debería estar en el diccionario. O estabas iterando en un bucle usando el índice de bucle como clave, sin tener en cuenta que un diccionario puede tener las claves 0, 1, 2, 10, 30, sin tener las intermedias, pues las claves no son índices, y pueden no ser contiguas.

Puedes detectar ese error para manejarlo de algún modo capturando la excepción:

```py
try:
   # Intentar acceder a una clave de un diccionario que podría no existir
   valor = diccionario[clave]
except KeyError:
   # Código que se ejecutará en caso de que se produzca esta excepción
   valor = 0
```

En el ejemplo anterior decidimos dar un valor `0` al resultado si la clave no existe, pero qué es lo que debería hacerse depende de cada caso. Podría ignorarse sin más, podría mostrarse un mensaje al usuario, etc...

### Cómo evitarlo

Otra forma de acceder a un elemento de un diccionario que no produce excepciones es utilizar esta otra sintaxis:

```py
valor = diccionario.get(clave)
```

En este caso, si `clave` no existe, se asignará a `valor` el resultado `None` y no se generará ninguna excepción. Esto puede ser preferible en algunos casos (me atrevo a decir que en la mayoría).

Además, puedes especificar otro valor por defecto si `None` no conviene a tu caso. Por ejemplo:

```py
valor = diccionario.get(clave, 0)
```

En este caso el valor por defecto a usar en caso de que la clave no esté presente sería `0`, lo que hace que esta línea sea equivalente a la implementación que antes hice con `try/except`.